# Not able to send mails to the same domain using SendGrid api

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using the SendGrid API to send the mail. It is working fine if, from and to domains are different. But it is not working if both from and to domains are same.

Comment: Hey @Shilpa. I do not have any large email provider and I am having the same problem with SendGrid api. Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the sent "from" email address' domain name is @yahoo.com or other large email provider, then all "DMARC" compliant mail servers will bounce the email unless the email was originated from the email provider's mail servers.

Otherwise, their should be no issue with sending emails where the "from" and "to" domain is the same.

For reference, this is yahoo's DMARC policy currently (as of 2/5/2019):
(https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN24050.html)

Yahoo recently updated the DMARC record with "p=reject" for Yahoo domains. This was done to protect our users from increasing email spam that uses Yahoo email addresses from other mail servers.

All DMARC compliant mail receivers (including Yahoo, Hotmail, and Gmail) are now bouncing emails sent as Yahoo email addresses that aren't sent through Yahoo servers.